# Is Deitel Intro to Python for Computer Science 2020 a resumed version of Deitel How to Program C, C++ and Java?

Tags: self-learning, programming, textbook, python, careers

**I am still not finding the right book for my career path.** My first book related to programming on my university was Deitel How to Program C for Programming 1 subject, for Programming 2 we use C++ How to Program 10th ed Global 2017. I not finded Deitel Python Books until 2020 so I decide starting with Mark Lutz 2013 and Programming with Python 2017 T.R. Padmanabhan, a lot of theory very few exercises I don't like, I like a book with plenty of exercises for learn.

Times Ago I decided to start with the Python Deitel New Book of the 2020 using the Function Chapter because I have previous knowledge using C, C++. I solved the function chapters of **Python Deitel**  but I solved **only 20 exercises**!. If we compare Deitel Python exercises of the Function Sections with **C Deitel is 54**, **Java** have A Deeper look of Methods **39 exercises**, Deitel **C++ Functions Chapter 61 exercises**.

I understand there is a difference between "How to Program" and "Intro to Computer Science but I want to learn How to program with Python **Can you recommend me a deep book of python for master my programming skills** at the level ( or more ) of the C++, C and Java? **My career paths is Data Science and Artificial Intelligence** so I need a lot of programming skills for that and I feel I need much more than what books are offering( if the books not offer enough exercises do you know some website or github repository for do that? ).

Books Reference:

Deitel P. Intro to Python for Computer Science and Data Science 2020.pdf

C How to Program Deitel 7th+++.pdf

C++ How to Program 10th ed Global 2017 by Paul Deitel

Deitel P.J., Deitel H.M. - Java How to Program 9th Edition.pdf

Answer (score 3):

A very nice book is Downey's ["Think Python" (2nd edition)](https://greenteapress.com/wp/think-python-2e). The link leads you to a free PDF, so you can take a look without cost. It teaches problem solving using Python, not Python per se. Make sure you get the second edition, which covers Python 3 (a somewhat different language than the obsolete Python 2).

There are lots of pointers to documentation at the [official Python site](https://www.python.org).

Comment: thank you for your answer looks like a nice book however I have some data related to the number of exercises of Deitel Python 2020 there are 538 examples and 471 exercises. I see a few in the Downey's book if we compare this book with Deitel.